# JMETER Recording Controller, getting always same state and nonce values from redirect URL

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, jmeter, openid

I've captured a JMeter scenario with Record Controller for Azure cloud, with Oauth2 + openId adhoc security layer config, and with 2 redirections before final redirect login webpage.

Checking root URL path (https://example.com/), with linux "wget " and nodeJS+Puppetter to get redirections, i've checked that the values from the redirections for "state" and "nonce" params from URL (that are calculated from root site with Javascript), are always the same values, captured from the Recording Scenario step (i mean, accessing root DNS with browser/wget/nodeJs, i'm getting dynamic values for "state" and "nonce" URL params in each call to main root URL, but from JMeter JMX recorded script, "state" and "nonce" params, are not been dynamic as from a browser, and always have the same values, despite i've checked step by step HTTP Request to see the way i can set them in Recorded Scenario to avoid the "static" same values.

In a step #1 I'm visiting url: https://example.com/

This url calculates a value that sends to the server, redirects me back to [https://example.com/login?state=[dynamic_calculated]&nonce=[dynamic_calculated]](https://example.com/login?state=%5Bdynamic_calculated%5D&nonce=%5Bdynamic_calculated%5D), and another redirection (2nd), gives me the login web access.

In my JMeter script, state and nonce params, are not calculated in each JMX script execution, having always the same values as captured initially with the Record Controller.

Could you please help me to check how can i get state and nonce param values in URL dynamically calculated, as from a browser navigation behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

[JMX capture for static values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBPMd.png)

Comment: Please look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) **records** the requests as it is by capturing it from the application which uses JMeter as the proxy. Any values which are supposed to be dynamic will be **hard-coded** and correspond the ones from the recorded request.

JMeter doesn't automatically detect/substitute dynamic content, you will have to:

1. Identify the source of the dynamic values (response body, [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) or URL), most probably they come in one of the previous requests
2. Extract them using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and store them into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
3. Replace recorded hard-coded values with the variables references from step 2

The process is known as [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)

There are some solutions for performing the correlation in semi-automated manner like [JMeter Correlation Recorder Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-the-jmeter-correlation-recorder-plugin) or fully-automated via [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000271458-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder) which is capable of exporting recorded requests in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic detection and correlation of the dynamic content.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, the thing is that those dynamic values, are been generated by a first javascript execution, that passes values to the server and the server in the way javascript calculates that dynamic values, sends back another dynamic values... the think is that the first javascript value, is always the same, as i'm getting always that same values and can't correlate them, due to that same execution of first javascript, that gives always the same value, to the server, and the server always send back all same values in each execution.

Comment: I don't know which value sets the javascript to calculate always the same result, over and over again, and the think is that in browser/wget/nodejs executions to root path URL, i'm getting dynamic javascript values without a problem, and the server sends back always dynamic values from that first javascript execution.

Comment: Trying JMeter Correlation Recorder Plugin, have the same result for value with the new capture, to trying to check correlation with this plugin to see it i can set the value that is giving the same result in all executions...